# grafana: installing only client tool

Tags: grafana

I've just installed grafana on my kubernetes.

I'd like to install `grafana-cli` in order to manage plugins.

Is there any way to install only `grafana-cli` without having to install all grafana package?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using ubuntu.